# why i take error LINK2019 when using dbghelp.h functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, linker-errors

i'm using VisualStudio 2019 for development and i try to use the library dbghelp.h in a C++ program, i just see the question [related to LINK2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334896/clrdump-c-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-registerfilter8) but set the sdk folder as other source for library doesnt't work for me.
in particular when i try to use the function *SymLoadModule64* i receive :

```
Severity Code Description   Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__SymLoadModule64@28 referenced in function "unsigned long __cdecl handleDebugEvent(struct _DEBUG_EVENT *)" (?handleDebugEvent@@YAKPAU_DEBUG_EVENT@@@Z) FaultInjector   C:\Users\User\source\repos\FaultInjector\FaultInjector\main.obj 1
```

The compilation succeed but the linking fails.
i really don't know how to solve the problem because i almost never face this type of issues

Comment: Looks like you did not link to the `Dbghelp.lib`. The documentation says its required here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symloadmodule64#requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symloadmodule64#requirements)

Comment: how can i link that library ? and why only that library need to be linked ?

Comment: Project Settings -> Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Comment: this definitely solve my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to drescherjm (comment below the queston), the problem has been solved by adding the library manually by Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input and in the right grid in *additional dependencies* adding **Dbghelp.lib** or maybe in general the library that created the linker problem

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symloadmodule64#requirements

mentions that `Dbghelp.lib` is a requirement. You need to update your Visual Studio project settings to link to this library.